# clean method in inheriting form

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

Let's say Form1 inherits after Form2. Form 1 has fields one, two, three. Can I define a method clean_one in Form2 (so clean for field inherited from other form) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean that Form2 inherits from Form1. In which case yes, you can define a clean method on the subclass that cleans fields defined on the superclass.